# How can you tell if a Tween is currently playing when using TweenLite?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can you tell if a Tween is currently playing when using TweenLite?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with TweenLite, you'll need to switch to TweenMax instead. Then you will be able to call `isTweening()` to determine this.

Hope that helps,
Tyler.

Answer (score 0):

Why not register a `onComplete` callback to check when the tween has finished instead (i.e. when it has finished playing)

Answer (score 0):

`isTweening()` no longer works. Use `isActive()`.